# How wrap image around cylinder in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, pixel-shader

I am trying wrap image around cylinder in silverlight. I looked a lot in Google but don't found anything. As I know it can be done with pixel shader, but don't know how.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a complete wrap onto cylinder, but you will get a starting idea/example:

(code is in GLSL, not in HLSL, but i think it will be not hard to convert it)

```
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
 vec2 cen = vec2(0.5,gl_TexCoord[0].y)-gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
 cen = vec2(pow(cen.x,1.7),pow(cen.y,2.2));
 cen.y = 3.9*sin(1.8*gl_TexCoord[0].x-2.3);
 vec2 mcoord = 1.65*vec2(-0.22+gl_TexCoord[0].x,1.95+gl_TexCoord[0].y);
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, mcoord+cen);
}
```

From this

[image]

you will get something like that[image]

Good luck

Comment: Exectly what I need. 
If anybody need HLSL here is it

sampler2D input : register(s0);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
 float4 color = 0;
 
 float2 center = float2(0.5, uv.x / 2);
 center = float2(pow(center.x, 1.7),pow(center.y, 2.2));
 center.y = 3.9 * sin(1.8 * uv.x - 2.3); 
 float2 mcoord = 1.65 * float2(-0.22 + uv.x, 1.95 + uv.y);
 uv.x = mcoord.x + center.x;
 uv.y = mcoord.y + center.y;
 color = tex2D(input, uv);
 
 return(color);
}

With this link you can learn how to use custom shader effects: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/pixel-effects/

Comment: can we get a generalized shader with input variables?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try Zam3d. I have used trial versions previously, and you can get the 3D shape and try and set the background to an image. Have a look and see if that helps.